# Расчет процентного соотношения в оконной функции

Tags: postgresql

в оконной функции прописываю расчет процентного соотношения, но, судя по результату запроса, не просчитывается деление на общее кол-во.
Суть задания: найдите процентное соотношение рейсов по типам самолетов от общего количества (flight_id-идентификатор рейса, aircraft_code-код самолета).
Где у меня ошибка в запросе?

```
select distinct(f.aircraft_code), 
    round((count(f.flight_id) over (partition by f.aircraft_code))*100/count(f.flight_id))
from flights f 
group by f.aircraft_code, f.flight_id
```

Comment: Оконные функции в случае наличия group by работают уже после группировки. Сначала все сгруппируйте по типам, получите количество по типам, потом оберните это внешним запросом и там уже делите количество на общее, собранное оконным sum()

Comment: Хотя может и sum(count(f.flight_id)) over() прокатит что бы уровень еще один не делать. И distinct кстати совершенно ни к чему, либо group by, либо distinct, что нибудь одно

Comment: `COUNT(..) OVER (PARTITION BY ..) / COUNT(..) OVER ()`, а GROUP BY вообще убрать.

Comment: @Akina Тогда исходное количество не группированных строк останется

Comment: @Mike *либо group by, либо distinct, что нибудь одно* Не совсем так - оконные функции считаются после GROUP BY, но до DISTINCT. Так что в данном конкретном случае применим только DISTINCT. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bb9cb6987b3b9379f413243331624d1 Впрочем, Постгресс вообще не пропустит запрос с GROUP BY...

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with flights  as (
  select '1' flight_id, 'A' aircraft_code union all 
  select '1', 'B' union all 
  select '1', 'B' union all 
  select '2', 'C'
)
select distinct
  f.*,
  count(*) over (partition by f.flight_id, f.aircraft_code)
   *100
   /count(*) over (partition by f.flight_id) as percent
from flights f
```